# What are the all the secret areas?

Tags: velocity-ultra

***Velocity Ultra***'s *Progress* screen shows 10 *Explorer #* badges, each stating "Discover secret area #".

Where are these 10 secret areas and how do I unlock them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Secret Areas" in the game are actually well hidden collectibles hidden around various levels.

Not long after I've posted this question, I've found the first Secret Area on my own, I'll keep track of all areas in this answer:

1. Zone 17, next to the 3rd yellow switch, teleport to the extreme right.
2. Zone 22, upper right branch. When you reach the end, scroll all the way to the top until you see the collectible then teleport to it.
3. Zone 26, in the first rightmost section (after the number 7 blue switch), scroll all the way to the top until you see an area, teleport to it for the the collectible.
4. Zone 28, after hitting the third yellow switch & entering the formerly blocked area, scroll the screen and teleport to the small area above you.
5. Zone 32, when near red and yellow switch #3, scroll the screen *all* the way to the top until you see and open space above you. Teleport for some survivors and the collectible.
6. Zone 35, when near blue switches #1 & 2, scroll the screen *all* the way to the top until you see and open space above you. Teleport for some survivors then teleport again for more survivors and the collectible.
7. Zone 39, at the very start, get rid of the blue turret and teleport to the gap of the left. Keep teleporting to the left and up until you see the collectible in a 1x1 space.
8. Zone 40, after the first, section past the red turrets and next to the blue turret, teleport to the right for some survivors and the collectible.
9. Zone 45, after yellow switch #7,  scroll all the way to the top until you see an area above you then teleport to it for the collectible.